# Failed to update subscription quantity for existing customer

Tags: php, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, subscription

I am trying to update existing stripe subscription quantity but getting error. I am not sure whether my code is correct or not as I am new on stripe.

I have retrieved existing subscription details and then tried to update subscription quantity.

```
 \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(config('services.stripe.secret'));

 $SubscriptionDtl= \Stripe\Subscription::retrieve("sub_F0IJi5YQiZZgKw");
 $quantity=$SubscriptionDtl['quantity'];
 $data=$SubscriptionDtl['data'];
 $customer=$SubscriptionDtl['customer'];
 $plan=$SubscriptionDtl['plan']; 

 try{

    $subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::update([
        'customer' => $customer,
        'items' => [
            [
                'plan' => $plan['id'],
                'quantity' =>$quantity+1,
            ],
        ],
    ]);

}catch(Exception $ex){
    die($ex->getMessage());

}
```

currently getting following error: "urlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given"

Expected to update  subscription quantity for the customers. Could please help me on this?

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/quantities  :  did you exact plan id in this $plan['id'] ?

Answer (score 0):

Update Below code block from

```php
$subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::update([
        'customer' => $customer,
        'items' => [
            [
                'plan' => $plan['id'],
                'quantity' =>$quantity+1,
            ],
        ],
    ]);
```

To this

```php
$subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::update([
        'customer' => $customer,
        'items' => [
            'plan' => $plan['id'],
            'quantity' =>$quantity+1,
        ],
    ]);
```